# How to use Jest globalSetup with Detox

Tags: jestjs, detox

I want to use `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` from Jest with Detox so that the detox setup only happens one time but Detox seems to fail if the init is not beforeAll.

Any suggestions?

Jest version :22.0.4
Detox Version:6.0.4

config:

```
"globalSetup": "./setUpDetox.js",
"globalTeardown": "./tearDownDetox.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the globalSetup and globalTeardown, setup and teardown the test environment from within your init. Just use jest's beforeAll and afterAll.

e2e/init.js

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;

jest.setTimeout(120000);

beforeAll(async () => {
  // custom setup
  console.log('Initializing Detox');
  await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
});

afterAll(async () => {
  // custom teardown
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

e2e/config.json

```
{
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" : "./init.js"
}
```